# Django Issues: ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a simple todo list using built-in generic views.

Here's my views.py

```
class TaskList(ListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'todo/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'formset' 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TaskFormSet(queryset=Task.objects.all())

    def post(self, request):
        formset = TaskFormSet(request.POST)

        if formset.has_changed() and formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        return redirect('/todo')
```

And here's my template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        <div>
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="+">
</form>
```

So when I submit form I get **['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']**

What's the deal?

Comment: That's where this exception comes from - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L88. Look at the data you receive when `post`ing (at the `request.POST`)